# Is there a way I can pass a variable ObservableCollection from ViewModel into a View?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mvvm, maui, .net-maui

I have a variable ObservableCollection BananasTeste declared in the ViewModel and I think I need to pass it into my View so I can change the ItemsSource of my CollectionView. I can show you my problem:

This is what I have in .xaml file:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding BananasTeste}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    <Grid>
                        <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Sem bananas!"></Label>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Frame BorderColor="#F5F5F5" CornerRadius="20" Padding="0, 10, 0, 10" WidthRequest="350" BackgroundColor="#F5F5F5">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:BananasViewModel}}, Path=GoToDetalhesBananaCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Grid>
                                    <!--<RoundRectangle WidthRequest="350" />-->
                                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="10">
                                        <Button CornerRadius="20" BackgroundColor="#F4E7E7" TextColor="#E96161" Text="{Binding Estado, StringFormat='{0}'}" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                        <Label FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Descricao}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
                                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                            <Image Source="calendario.svg" HeightRequest="15" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"></Image>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Data, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            <Image Source="relogio.svg" HeightRequest="15" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"></Image>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Data, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" Padding="5, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

And in my ViewModel I have this code:

```
public partial class BananasViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private List<BananaDTO> banana;
        public List<BananaDTO> Banana
        {
            get
            {
                return banana;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref banana, value);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<BananaDTO> BananasTeste { get; set; } = new();
        public ObservableCollection<BananaDTO> BananasPendentes { get; set; } = new();

public BananasViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Bananas";

            banana = new List<BananaDTO>();

            TesteGetBananaAsync(commandParam);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void TesteGetBananaAsync(string obj)
        {
            banana = await GetBananaAsync(obj);

            if (BananasTeste.Count != 0)
                BananasTeste.Clear();

            if (BananasPendentes.Count != 0)
                BananasPendentes.Clear();

            foreach (var x in banana)
            {
                BananasTeste.Add(x);

                if (x.IdBananaEstado == 1)
                {
                    BananasPendentes.Add(x);
                }
            }

            //var lista = BananasTeste.Where(x => x.IdBananaEstado == 1);
            //BananasTeste = new ObservableCollection<BananaDTO>(lista);
        }

        public async Task<List<BananaDTO>> GetTarefaAsync(string idCond)
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return await Task.FromResult(new List<BananaDTO>());

            try
            {
                var ban = new List<BananaDTO>();
                if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Sem internet!", $"Por favor verifique a conexão à internet", "OK");
                    return await Task.FromResult(task);
                }
                else
                {
                    var urlBuilder_ = new StringBuilder();
                    urlBuilder_.Append("/Bananas/");
                    if (idCond != null)
                    {
                        urlBuilder_.Append(idCond);
                    }

                    IsBusy = true;
                    var response = await MakeRequest(urlBuilder_.ToString(), Method.Get);
                    if (response != null && response.IsSuccessful)
                    {
                        ban = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BananaDTO>>(response.Content);
                    }
                }
                return await Task.FromResult(task);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get bananas: {ex.Message}");
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Erro!", ex.Message, "OK");
                return await Task.FromResult(new List<BananaDTO>()); ;
            }
            finally
            {
                //await Task.Delay(2000);
                IsBusy = false;
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }
}
```

And in my View, the .xaml.cs file:

```
    public partial class BananasPage : ContentPage
    {
        public BananasPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
        }
    
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
    
            // This commented line is what I want to do:
            //MyCollectionView.ItemsSource = BananasTeste.Where(x => x.IdBananaEstado == 1).ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the ItemSource at runtime, but you can change the contents of the item source e.g., use filtered values from `Banana` list to populate it. It's a little unclear exactly what issue it is that you are having, could you elaborate what exactly your issue is or at least what you are trying to do?

Comment: How are you assigning the page’s BindingContext?

Comment: I'm assigning the page's binding context in the xaml file:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BananasApp.MVVM.Views.BananasPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BananasApp.MVVM.ViewModels"
             Title="Bananas">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:BananasViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

Comment: I want to filter values in the BananasTeste when the page displays/appears. How can I achieve this?

Comment: public partial class BananasPage : ContentPage
    {
        private YourViewModel vm;
        public BananasPage(YourViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this.vm = vm;
        }
}

I think that's what you are looking for, then you can reference the values from your vm. but it's not a good practice

Comment: @LeandroToloza , James Montemagno has a couple of this implementation on youtube, and this is DependencyInjection as he said. Could you explain why is not a good practice?

Comment: @ValiMatieș because you need to abstract business logic from ui, thats the porpouse of MVVM, anyway there are few cases that you can implement it on xaml.cs (UI)